# Setup Project: user enters a value then store it in a text file or database

Tags: visual-studio, dialog, setup-project

As the title said, how can i do that?
I've search some tuts on google, but only for creating simple setup projects.[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz4Zx.png)

When the user enters 'something', that value will be stored in a textfile or database after installation and is located in the application location (ProgramFiles). thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

That dialog looks like a TextBoxes dialog, and that dialog has uppercase property names for the content. If it's TextBoxes(A) the property name is probably EDITA1 so you use it in the format [EDITA1] to pass it to custom actions. Without knowing exactly what kind of custom action you'll be using I can't be explicit, but you'll probably start by having [EDITA1] in the CustomActionData property of the custom action. For (a bad) example, in a VBScript custom action you'd use the value session.property ("CustomActionData").